# Can grafting still work if the rootstock and scion are a little dried out during transit?

Tags: apples, grafting, scion, rootstock

I've very recently received my bareroot grafted plants by parcel. Their scion and rootstock grafts resembles somewhat golden-yellow in hue in the spot where they were grafted. Apparently they weren't grafted properly and they show gaps in the place that haven't been fused(?)

Should I wrap them in plastic so as to set them properly in humid conditions?

Will they survive? Or should I assume they're dead? P.s. when I wound them to check whether they're dead, they show cambium as green which proves that they seemingly aren't dead.

Here are images for your reference:[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

P.p.s: They are Anna Israeli Apples (low chill).

Is there someone with experience in grafting who can give thoughts on it? Should I try to re-graft them?

Comment: Moving a fragile graft? I wouldn't. Wrapping is your best bet. I'd bet the graft is okay. Remove the sprouts below it (a very good sign) to drive energy up. And I'd send pics to the grower and ask for a refund or credit for giving me a heart attack.

Comment: I feel less bad about my alleged amateur grafting skills after seeing this as an alleged professional job... it it arrived both unwrapped and not showing any callusing to speak of, I'm seriously unimpressed. If you unwrapped it, wrap it back up ASAP.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's what were my initial thoughts, now that the time has been passed and my hopes to claim refund have been shattered. P.s. I am aware that the lower buds divert away the energy from scion I've left buds on rootstock of 1/9 plants to clone it for certified rootstock next year ;)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I removed the wrapping after 2 weeks to check if the calluses were formed. And post that only 2/10 plants I purchased showed budbreak on scion. This cemented my belief that the grafts themselves were dry at the time of grafting. And some of them were even broken. Had the scionwood been fresh, the grafts would've shown success in within 2 weeks as suggested by various research papers.